# Two arrays comibation under the same key

Tags: php, arrays, key

I need to combine 2 arrays under the same key by appending *`Array2`* to *`Array1`*:

```
Array1
(
    [0] => value1
    [1] => value2
    [2] => value3
    [3] => value4
    [4] => value5
    [5] => value6
    [6] => value7
)
Array2
(
    [0] => add1
    [1] => add2
    [2] => add3
    [3] => add4
    [4] => add5
    [5] => add6
    [6] => add7
)
```

so that *`Array3`* looks like this:

```
Array1
(
    [0] => value1add1
    [1] => value2add2
    [2] => value3add3
    [3] => value4add4
    [4] => value5add5
    [5] => value6add6
    [6] => value7add7
)
```

I searched through php.net but I wasn't able to find anything. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance for your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`array_map`<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) makes looping superfluous in this case:

```
$arr1 = array('value1','value2','value3');
$arr2 = array('add1','add2','add3');
$merged = array_map(function($x, $y) { return $x . $y; }, $arr1, $arr2);
```

If you don't have PHP5.3+ (or you don't like lambda) you'll need to define the closure in a separate function and reference that function's name instead inside your `array_map` call.

Comment: Works like a charm. I have accepted yours due to the **array_map** Thank you!

Comment: No problem. It's never bad to avoid a loop if you can accomplish the same thing with a built-in array function!

Answer (score 2):

Just do a loop:

```
if (count($arr1) == count($arr2))
{
  $arr3 = array();
  foreach ($arr1 as $key => $val)
    $arr3 = $val . $arr2[$key];
}
else
{
  echo "Arrays should be of same size!";
  $arr3 = array();
  for ($i = 0, $i < min(count($arr1),count($arr2)); $i++)
    $arr3 = $arr1[$i] . $arr2[$i];
}
```

(Exact implementation should depend on your input values)

Comment: First of all thank you and konsolenfreddy for your extremely fast answers. Both examples look to work perfectly but an addition was required **[]** `$arr3[] = $val . $arr2[$key];` I will accept rdlowrey's answer because it works better in my case (my arrays have the same size) but yours has a complete `if` loop which might help others in the future. I am upvoting all 3 of you. Thank you!

Comment: @triump, rdlowrey's `array_map` is a more elegant solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

Soemthing like this:

```
foreach($array1 as $k=> $value){
    $array3[$k] =  $value . $array2[$k];
}
print_r($array3);
```

Mind you, it will only take as many items as `$array1` contains. If `$array2` is larger, other values will be ignored.

Comment: Thank you for your superfast answer!